# Добавить иной класс img по ID элемента

Tags: php, html

Добрый день!

Помогите разобраться как правильно прописать условие, если `ID` "1432", то `<li id="photo-0" class="current test">` вместо `class="current"`, учитывая содержимое текущего кода. Я вижу, что у меня уже пересекается несколько раз условие с интересующим меня `ID`, но не знаю, как правильно и куда конкретно прописать.

```
<div class='catalog-detail' data-val='<?=$arResult['ID'];?>'>
    <div class='catalog-grey-block group'>
        <div class='catalog-detail-left-block'>
            <div class="item_slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?
                $images = array();

                if(is_array( $arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"] ) ){$images[] = $arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"];}
                foreach( $arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] as $arPhoto ){    $images[] = $arPhoto;}
                $bIsOneImage = count($images) == 1;
                ?>
                <?foreach( $images as $key => $arPhoto ){?>
                    <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
                        <?//pr($arPhoto); //$img = CFile::ResizeImageGet( $arPhoto, array( "width" => 1000, "height" => 800 ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, true, array() );?>
                       <?if($arResult['ID']!='1432'):?> <a rel='gallery' href="<?=$arPhoto["SRC"]?>"  class='fancy' > <?endif;?>
                            <?$img = CFile::ResizeImageGet( $arPhoto, array( "width" => 534, "height" => 307 ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true, array() );?>
                            <img border="0" src="<?=$img["src"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_ALT"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_DETAIL_PICTURE_FILE_TITLE"]?>" />
                        <?if($arResult['ID']!='1432'):?> </a>  <?endif;?>
                    </li>
                <?}?>
            </ul>
            <?if(count($images) > 1 ){?>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <ul id="thumbs">
                        <?foreach( $images as $key => $arPhoto ){?>
                            <?$img = CFile::ResizeImageGet( $arPhoto, array( "width" => 130, "height" => 76 ), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, true, array() );?>
                            <li <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
                                <a href='javascript:void(0);'>
                                    <img border="0" src="<?=$img["src"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?}?>
                        <?if (count($images)>3):?><?endif;?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <span class="thumbs_navigation"></span>
            <?}?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить проверку на ид. Вместо

```
<li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
```

написать два варианта

```
<?php if ($id == 1432) { ?>
    <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current test"' : ''?>>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
<?php } ?>
```

Откуда взять $id из вашего кода не понятно, поэтому написал просто переменную.

Comment: А так не будет правильно? <?if($arResult['ID']!='1432') {?>
    <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current test"' : ''?>>
<?if } else { ?>
    <li id="photo-<?=$key?>" <?=$key == 0 ? 'class="current"' : ''?>>
<?endif;?>

Comment: Либо может проще как-то применить класс к IMG с этим ID вместо применения класса к <li id="photo-0">? Просто дописать. Мне, в принципе, нужно только, чтобы у этого IMG был дополнительный класс "test". Вот здесь в этой строке, например, закрывается конкретно для этого элемента, если я понимаю правильно, тег <a>, то есть при клике на него его картинка не открывается в отличие от других элементов.